# 2131755153 (1) in toast and 10027 error code while use Huawei Kit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services

I have integrated Huawei Site Kit in my app and it works fine. But suddenly few days ago it stops working and when I launch app I can see Toast with message `2131755153 (1)`

Also I can see `10027` error code in logs.

So, what is the problem and how I can fix it?

Comment: why negative rating? it's real trouble with Huawei mobile services..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to login to developer console and chose plan (Pay as you go) for every paid feature, including `SiteKit`, which you use. Note, that you can have monthly free limit on your account (i.e $300/month), so you may still use features without any payments as you have to.

There is a picture, how chosen plan looks like in developer console:

[image]